# How we can put authentication for the HTTP request in retrofit?

Tags: android, retrofit

How can I get an authentication for a URL, to which we have to send a request using Retrofit?

Comment: What kind of authentication? What part of the request does it need included in?

Comment: Now I am using the following code,HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);
httpGet.addHeader(BasicScheme.authenticate(
  new UsernamePasswordCredentials("username", "password"),
  "UTF-8", false));
HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet); ,How can i can achieve this using retrofit?

Answer (score 0):

**This depends on the the authentication method used by the service server.**

For example, Twitch.tv provides "Authorization Code Flow" as one of the methods for authentication. In this method you provide the auth parameters in the request URL:

```
https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/oauth2/authorize
    ?response_type=code
    &client_id=[your client ID]
    &redirect_uri=[your registered redirect URI]
    &scope=[space separated list of scopes]
```

Other methods requires specifying the auth parameters in the request header.

If you provide me with more information, regarding the authentication method used by the service you want to talk to, I may be able to provide you with a specific answer, or even with working code (If I have the time).